# EditText margin lost on changing background color

Tags: android, android-edittext

I've created 5 Edit-text in a Linear layout with horizontal orientation and they have no padding or margins set. When I change the background color of these Edit-text's the borders are lost. Kindly help how to make sure my edit text do not loose their borders.Following is the code snippet.

Saving the padding and reassigning it back hasn't helped!

```
private void setToNonEditMode(EditText textBox, boolean nonEditMode){

        if(nonEditMode){
            textBox.setClickable(false);
            textBox.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.transparent));
            textBox.setFocusable(false);
            textBox.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
        }else{
            textBox.setClickable(true);
            textBox.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
            textBox.setFocusable(true);
            textBox.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried defining an edit text as a shape and then assign it? 
I see you create your EditText programatically, but here is something you could try:

1. Create a drawable as an xml in your res/drawable folder:

   ```
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
     <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
         <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#000000"/>
    </shape>
   ```
2. Use this:

   ```
    textBox.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.name_of_your_xml_shape_file);
   ```

Comment: No I haven't created my Edit-text programatically and can you please explain why could this really happen??

Comment: Because in your XML, you assign a background color to your EditText via android:background, and now you can't use this once again for a border color. I am not 100% sure, but I think that's the reason.

So you have to create a XML Drawable for this. Then you can set the background of the EditText as any color you like, and the background of the 'shape' of the EditText with a <stroke> /border/.

Comment: Alright Idimitrov I will try that. Thanks for your help.

Comment: It works a little more, as it adds the black stroke (I suggest using a #AA000000 color for that) but it's still not as good as the original style: shades and focus are still broken